# Directly opening url with stateparam not working in angularjs

Tags: angular-ui-router

I have url like

http://localhost:8000/articles/2345 when clicked within angular, it works fine. This URL's have to be linked from other websites also. But i get error like

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

I am using ui-router like below

```
.state('kbca', {
      parent : 'root',
      url: "/articles/:articleId",
      templateUrl: "views/abc/abc.html,
      controller: "abcCtrl",
      data : {
          authorizedRoles : [ROLES.PUBLIC]
      }
    })
```

and config like

```
.config(function($locationProvider){
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
});
```

and i have index.html where in i have made base as

```
<div id="wrap">

    <div ui-view></div>
</div> <!-- end wrap -->
<base href="/">
```

i tried lots of options on web. But nothing seems to be working for me.

Here is my server conf

```
server {
    listen 8000;
    root D:/xampp/htdocs/web/myweb/app;
    index index.html index.htm;
    server_name localhost;
    location / {
       try_files $uri  $uri/ /index.html;

    }
    location /mysvcs {
            proxy_pass      http://localhost:8080/mymvc;
            proxy_set_header Host localhost;
    }

    location /mymvc {
            proxy_pass      http://localhost:8080/mymvc;
            proxy_set_header Host localhost;
    }

}
```

Comment: This must be a server issue. Are you sure configuration is ok? https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode

Comment: @Radim Köhler - Updated server conf.

Comment: *Sorry, I won't help you with your server.. (I am running MS world)... but it should not be so big issue... I guess*